# nodejs + vmware vsphere sdk soap connection

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, vmware, vsphere

I am trying to use NodeJS with soap and connect to VMWare's WSDL on a ESX or a virtual center but have been unable to do so. Any pointers would be really helpful.

I am using node-soap and I also found a php tutorial using soap to connect to ESX http://www.helixstorm.com/connecting-vsphere-api-php5-soap/

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how far you have made it on this but here is what the initial SOAP request should look like>  http://pastebin.com/iXWcgepf

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a connection to VMware's SOAP API using the [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) module.  The key is that their interface requires cookie authentication, so in addition to this module, you'll also need the [soap-cookie](https://github.com/shanestillwell/soap-cookie) module.

I recently authored a [low-level wrapper](https://github.com/reedog117/node-vsphere-soap) that maintains a connection with a vCenter/ESXi host and allows you to issue vSphere API methods directly to it. You might get some inspiration from the source code I uploaded.